# Cakephp: User Model with Country / State dropdowm

Tags: cakephp

I am using Auth component for user login and registration. I want to add Country and State dropdowns to my User Model. Can someone help me with the required association in the Model files?

```
class User extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'User';

    var  $belongsTo  ="Country" ;
}


<?php
class Country extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Country';

    var $hasMany = array('User');

}?>
```

My view:

```
echo $form->input('country_id');
```

But I am getting an empty dropdowm!

Comment: whats the big deal? did you try anything yet? the code that doesnt work you can then post here.

Comment: yes, let me update with what I have!

Comment: tip: bake your code. this way cake will do the work for you. and your answer's gonna answer itself

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for the tip! Never came up to my mind that I should have tried baking! I have more associations to come...will definitely try bake scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **belongsTo** definition is incorrect. The belongsTo attribute must be an array:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Country');
```

Then in your **Users** controller, ensure you're getting the list of *countries*:

```
$countries = $this->User->Country->find('list');
$this->set(compact('countries'));
```

And your view will look something like:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo __('Edit User'); ?></legend>
      <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        // more fields
        echo $this->Form->input('country_id');
      ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

Comment: where would the code for finding and setting countries go within in the Controller?

Comment: The action that accompanies your form.

Comment: That worked! But the drop down is containing country ids instead of names!

Comment: You need to set the `$displayField` of your Country model. It will probably be `public $displayField = 'country'`