# cakePHP: User Association with Country and State dropdown

Tags: cakephp

To the extension of my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512650/cakephp-user-model-with-country-state-dropdowm)

I seeing the following error while doing an ajax call for populating the states dropdown -

2011-12-15 01:15:51 Debug: Populating state for country id #99
2011-12-15 01:15:51 Debug: Notice (8): Undefined property: User::$State in [C:\xampp\htdocs\dearmemoir\app\controllers\users_controller.php, line 236]

Here is my code from the controller -

```
function get_states($country_id = null){
        CakeLog::write('debug', 'Populating state for country id #' . $country_id ) ;
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->set('states',$this->User->State->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('State.country_id' => $country_id))));
}
```

I see that ajax call is being made and I am able to display the selected value in the controller.

And here are Models -

#### state.php

```
<?php

class State extends AppModel {

    var $displayField = 'state_name';

    var $name = 'State';

    var $hasMany = array('User');

    var $hasOne = array ('Country');

}?>
```

#### country.php

```
<?php
class Country extends AppModel {

    var $displayField = 'country_name';

    var $name = 'Country';

    var $hasMany = array('User','State');

}?>
```

#### user.php

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'User';

    var  $belongsTo  = array('Country');

------

}
```

I am unable to figure out what might possible be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

urg...i figured out-

My user model is missing the association with State

```
var  $belongsTo  = array('Country');
```

should be

```
var  $belongsTo  = array('Country','State');
```